# ListItem Click event not working when i am putting ListItem's button's click event in android

Tags: android, button, android-listview, listitem, custom-adapter

I have made an activity in that I have a ListView,With custom ListAdater,In ListView some ListItem will have button and some having not,So the ListItems which are not having button are clicked easily,But the ListItems which are having button are not clickable,I have tried to find any solution if any buddy knows help me,Thank you in advance..!My chunk of code is:
**ListItem.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_trans_id_raw"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Trans ID"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_trans_desc_raw"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Description"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_trans_date_raw"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:text="Date"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_trans_date_raw"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:text="status"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_issue"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_status"
        android:background="@drawable/issu_refund_btn"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**CustoAdapter.java**

```
package com.epe.tp.adapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.sax.StartElementListener;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.ep.trustedPAYER.R;
import com.epe.tp.ui.DisputeSteponeActivity;
import com.epe.tp.ui.HomeActivity;
import com.epe.tp.util.Const;

public class SentPaymentAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> sentPaymentArray;
    private Context mContext;

    Intent i;

    public SentPaymentAdapter(Context paramContext, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> paymentList) {
        this.mContext = paramContext;
        this.sentPaymentArray = paymentList;

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return this.sentPaymentArray.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int paramInt) {
        return Integer.valueOf(paramInt);
    }

    public long getItemId(int paramInt) {
        return paramInt;
    }

    public View getView(final int paramInt, View paramView, ViewGroup paramViewGroup) {
        LayoutInflater localLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext.getSystemService("layout_inflater");
        Viewholder localViewholder = null;
        if (paramView == null) {
            paramView = localLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.raw_dashboard, paramViewGroup, false);
            localViewholder = new Viewholder();

            localViewholder.tv_date = ((TextView) paramView.findViewById(R.id.tv_trans_id_raw));
            localViewholder.tv_desc = ((TextView) paramView.findViewById(R.id.tv_trans_desc_raw));
            localViewholder.tv_amount = ((TextView) paramView.findViewById(R.id.tv_trans_date_raw));
            localViewholder.tv_status = ((TextView) paramView.findViewById(R.id.tv_status));
            localViewholder.btn_issue = ((Button) paramView.findViewById(R.id.btn_issue));
            localViewholder.tv_status.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            paramView.setTag(localViewholder);

        } else {

            localViewholder = (Viewholder) paramView.getTag();
        }

        localViewholder.tv_date.setText(sentPaymentArray.get(paramInt).get(Const.TAG_DATE_ADDED));
        localViewholder.tv_desc.setText(sentPaymentArray.get(paramInt).get(Const.TAG_DESCRIPTION));
        localViewholder.tv_amount.setText(sentPaymentArray.get(paramInt).get(Const.TAG_ORDER_AMOUNT));
        localViewholder.tv_status.setText(sentPaymentArray.get(paramInt).get(Const.TAG_STATUS));
        if (localViewholder.tv_status.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Paid")) {
            localViewholder.btn_issue.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            localViewholder.btn_issue.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.issu_refund_btn);
        } else if (localViewholder.tv_status.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Processing")) {
            localViewholder.btn_issue.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            localViewholder.btn_issue.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.issue_refund_btn);
        } else {
            localViewholder.btn_issue.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        localViewholder.btn_issue.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(mContext, DisputeSteponeActivity.class);
                mContext.startActivity(i);

            }
        });
        return paramView;

    }

    static class Viewholder {

        TextView tv_date;
        TextView tv_desc;
        TextView tv_amount;
        TextView tv_status;
        Button btn_issue;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `android:focusable="false"` to all the textviews and button.